# Draw multiple rectangle in single image in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm trying to draw rectangles on image using x,y,height and width but i can only able to draw one rectangle at a time can't able to draw multiple rectangle in single image.

```
JSX code:
          {this.state.books.map((object) => (
              <div class="img-overlay-wrap"style={{ marginLeft: "27%" }}>
     
              <img  src={`data:image/png;base64,${object.image_id}`} style={{ height:`${object.hw[0]}` , width:`${object.hw[1]}`}} alt="" />
              
              <svg  width={object.hw[1]} height={object.hw[0]} >
              
             <g >
               <rect  x={object.bbox[0]} y={object.bbox[1] - object.bbox[3]}  width={object.bbox[2]} height={object.bbox[3] }
             style={{stroke:"red",}} fill-opacity="0.0" />
                         <text x={object.bbox[0]} y={object.bbox[1]} font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="red">{object.category_id}</text>
             </g>
               
               Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
                  </svg> 
               
                  <h3>Confidence:{object.score}</h3>
                  <h3>Category Id:{object.category_id}</h3>
              <p>{object.bbox[0]},{object.bbox[1]},{object.bbox[3]},{object.bbox[2]}</p>
  </div>
            ))}
```

i am using map function to iterate through the array but i couldn't able to draw all the rectangles in single image please help me

Answer (score 1):

I've done This, and it worked for me, maybe it is useful for you:

```
const rectInfos = [
       [{top:"0px",left:"0px",color:"green"},{top:"0px",left:"500px",color:"yellow"}],
       [{top:"150px",left:"0px",color:"blue"},{top:"150px",left:"500px",color:"black"}],
    ]
    const rects = rectInfos.map((row,i)=>
        row.map((svgElement,j)=>
            <svg key={`i+${i}+${j}+j`} style={{width:"500px", height:"150px",position: "absolute", top:svgElement.top, left:svgElement.left}}>
                <rect style={{fill:svgElement.color, width:"500px", height:"150px"}} />
            </svg>
        )
    )

    return (
        
        <div style={{position: "relative", width:"1000px", height:"300px"}}>
            {rects}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This case is for 4 **rectangles** with the same **width** and **height** in a parent `div`.
[image]

Comment: thanks but i want the box to be on image for object detection purpose. here is the full code   {this.state.books.map((object) => (
<div class="img-overlay-wrap"style={{ marginLeft: "27%" }}>
<img  src={`data:image/png;base64,${object.image_id}`} style={{ height:`${object.hw[0]}` , width:`${object.hw[1]}`}} alt="" />
<svg width={object.hw[1]} height={object.hw[0]} key={index}>     
<g >
<rect key={object.score} x={object.bbox[0]} y={object.bbox[1] - object.bbox[3]}  width={object.bbox[2]} height={object.bbox[3] }
style={{stroke:"red",}} fill-opacity="0.0" />
</g>
</svg> 
</div>
  ))}